# Are these sentences basically the same?

Tags: sentence-construction, difference

> 1) That's why I'd (I would) just let you know that I'm single.
>
> 2) That's why I just wanted to let you know that I'm single.

Are these sentences basically the same?

Comment: Hi JackSparrow :) In my opinion, the use of "would" in the first sentence implies conditional mood or context, or the possibility of something being done - for example "I would just let you know that I'm single if I knew it was going to avoid all this awkwardness!".  It also sounds "past tense" to me - i.e. what you might have done (if a certain condition was true).  With the second sentence, its more affirmative and present tense - you are telling someone "this is the reason why I wanted to tell you that I'm single".  The use of "just" isn't strictly necessary but adds emphasis.

Comment: Regarding sentence 1, I agree with both of @Paul’s points (there seems to be a conditional and/or past tense context). Another way to put this is, it has a hypothetical meaning. For example, discussing with someone what you would have done if you had first met them in a bar.  The second sentence is more standard although the context here seems to be speaking of the recent past. For example:- I said, “Hi, I’m single.” and she got angry for some reason, carrying on about just wanting to have a good time, and I said, “I don’t understand. That’s why I just wanted to let you know I’m single.”